# jQuery .trigger() not sending extraParameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I am using jQuery function `.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )` to trigger a function in a global object variable. The function runs, but with no extra parametrs, that are passed to the trigger function in an array, as the [documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters). What is wrong here?

The code: [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/urwo909p/)

```
var loc={
    connect: function(e, p1, p2) {
        console.log(p1);  //this returns undefined
        console.log(p2);  //this returns undefined
    }
}  

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(loc).trigger("connect",["a","b"]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one work:

```
function  loc(){
        /*connect: function(e, p1, p2) {
            console.log(p1);  //this returns undefined
            console.log(p2);  //this returns undefined */
        //}
        $(this).bind("connect",function(e,p1,p2){
            console.log(p1);  
            console.log(p2);
        })
    }  
    var lock = new loc();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(lock).trigger("connect",["a","b"]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(loc).on('connect', function(e, param1, param2) {
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
});
```